# NSLayoutConstraint and MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

In my viewDidLoad method, I have code to create a MKMapView, some constraints, and a UIToolbar:

I have a MKMapView:

```
MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
[mapView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
mapView.showsUserLocation = TRUE;
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
mapView.delegate = self;

[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];

[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

I create 2 constraints to make it full screen:

```
NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray array];

[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[mapView]|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mapView)]];

[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[mapView]|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mapView)]];

[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Works great. But when I try to add anything to the map view:

```
 UIToolbar *topBar = [[UIToolbar alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[topBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
topBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

[mapView addSubview:topBar];
```

it throws an error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[MKMapView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UIView.m:5776
2013-01-10 10:24:17.503 Landscout 2[2001:14003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. MKMapView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

From my understanding, since I am adding a new view to the map view, the map view needs to re-calculate all the constraints in it? Basically a drawRect method for constraints.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In which method are you creating `UIToolbar *topBar` and adding it as a subview?

Comment: the code is all within viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the issue by simply using a content view to stuff everything into.  Instead of adding the tool bar to myMapView, i add it to myContentView.

I'm pretty sure MKMapView isn't set up to use constraints yet. MapView won't call `[super layoutSubviews]` which would eventually lead to `[UIView layoutSubviews]`.

Another possible solution i'd imagine is to add a category to MKMapView that would override `-layoutSubview` to call `[super layoutSubview]`, but i don't know how to find out what else is in the `[MKMapView layoutSubview]` that i would need to add.

Comment: Yup - Could not add a constraint to MKMapView either

Comment: Found this post that does the same as you, thought you might be interested in the read. http://www.karlmonaghan.com/2013/09/03/ios-6-auto-layout-and-mkmapview/