# MKMapView custom callOutView with auto layout iOS 6 vs. iOS7

Tags: ios6, ios7, mkmapview, autolayout, mkannotationview

Hej Folks,

my apps crashes on a MKMapView under iOS 6 if I use auto layout for the callout view. With iOS 7 this works fine.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
CustomMapAnnotation *annotation = (CustomMapAnnotation *)view.annotation;

if([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomMapAnnotation class]]) {
    CustomMapCalloutView *calloutView = [CustomMapCalloutView new];
    calloutView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    calloutView.titleLabel.text = annotation.titleText;
    calloutView.subTitleLabel.text = annotation.subTitleText;
    calloutView.distanceTextLabel.text = annotation.distanceText;

    [view addSubview:calloutView];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"callOutView": calloutView};
    NSArray *hConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[callOutView(150)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    NSArray *vConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[callOutView(50)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    NSLayoutConstraint *xConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:calloutView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *yConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:calloutView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

    [view addConstraint:xConstraint];
    [view addConstraint:yConstraint];

    [view addConstraints:hConstraints];
    [view addConstraints:vConstraints];
}}
```

The console shows the following error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[MKAnnotationView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIView.m:5776 2013-10-27
>   13:39:18.519 PartySmarty[9825:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout
>   still required after executing -layoutSubviews. MKAnnotationView's
>   implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

Can somebody give me a hint where the problem is? The CustomCalloutView works also with auto layout and I don't overwrite layoutSubviews within.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591366/subclassing-mkannotationview-with-use-of-auto-layout didn't help me, I don't want to switch back to the frame model :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14283435/701900) points me in the right direction. I create a category on the MKAnnotationView, override the layoutSubviews method and call the super method.

This works also on iOS 7.